# Solutions for an electron near a 1D Coulomb

Tags: quantum-mechanics, homework-and-exercises, wavefunction, schroedinger-equation, coulombs-law

I am only a amateur solving the time-independent Schrödinger equation, and I only know how to solve the 1D box.  When I went to search up more realistic examples, i.e. the Coulomb well, no one seemed to provide a solution with steps on how to derive it.  Can someone, please provide an answer with detailed explanations?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schrödinger_equation

Comment: What you're looking for is basically any upper-level book on quantum mechanics.  Griffiths, Merzbacher, Liboff, and Shankar are all good choices.

Comment: @my2cts Wait in the wiki page the equation for the hydrogen atom involves the "position" of the electron, but i thought there was no such thing as a exact position for a electron?

Comment: @LolulolulCoder which part? In quantum mechanics, "position" is an mathematical operation. You are right that the electron has no definite position but you can use this operator to calculate things like the mean position of the electron, as where do you find it is a matter of probability

Comment: @LolulolulCoder Correct. In the hydrogen Schrödinger equation the potential energy of the electron proton pair appears with a distance $r$, yet we cannot identify it as the electron position wrt to the proton. It’s a mystery.

Answer (score 3):

The 1D Coulomb potential is very pathological. The potential
$$V(x)\propto \frac1{|x|}$$
is not penetrable (zero transmission), see [1](https://doi.org/10.1119/1.10585). As for the eigenproblem, see [2](https://doi.org/10.1098/rspa.2015.0534):

> As a purely mathematical problem, it follows from the general theory of singular differential equations, as in Whittaker & Watson, that equation (1.1) does not have a complete set of solutions. There is a complete set of well-behaved odd-parity solutions, as the potential term on the left of equation (1.1) is finite for such wave functions, but well-behaved even-parity solutions are absent. The lack of these solutions is not acceptable for a problem in quantum mechanics.

The potential can be amended by removing the singularity. For example, the replacement
$$\frac1{|x|}\to\frac1{a+|x|}$$
for some distance $a$ which leads to confluent hypergeometric functions.

If you are just learning quantum mechanics for the first time, it is best to skip it and go to other potentials (here is a lists: [List of quantum-mechanical systems with analytical solutions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_quantum-mechanical_systems_with_analytical_solutions)
, I would recommend the harmonic oscillator). You can also try to learn how to deal with 3D systems, that way you would be able to tackle the more realistic 3D Coulomb potential (hydrogen atom).

### References

1. Andrews, M. "Singular potentials in one dimension." American Journal of Physics 44.11 (1976): 1064-1066.
2. Loudon, Rodney. "One-dimensional hydrogen atom." Proceedings of the Royal Society A: Mathematical, Physical and Engineering Sciences 472.2185 (2016): 20150534.

Comment: so do we take the limit as a approaches 0?

Comment: @LolulolulCoder that works to get some kind of eigenenergy but you still lose the eigenfunctions.